# Proving $\left\| \frac{\vec{v}}{\|\vec{v}\|}\right\| =1$, $\vec{v}\ne \vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I've been trying to prove that $\left\Vert\dfrac{\vec{v}}{\Vert\vec{v}\Vert}\right\Vert=1, \quad \vec{v}\ne \vec{0}$. This is my attempt:

\begin{align}
\vec{v}&\in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad \vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix} \\
\Vert\vec{v}\Vert&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2} \\
\frac{\vec{v}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2}}&=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{v_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2}} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{v_n}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2}} \end{pmatrix} =\vec{u} \\ \\
\Vert\vec{u}\Vert^2&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{v_k^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2}\right)
\end{align}

I think it is the last step that is either overcomplicated or wrong.

Comment: Are you aware that $\frac{v}{||v||}$ is a vector?

Comment: Just use $\Vert\alpha x\Vert=|\alpha|\Vert x\Vert$. But, you can "bring the summation into the numerator" in your last expression, which will complete your proof (you should have $\Vert u\Vert^2$, there on the left hand side).

Comment: Apparently you meant $\|\frac{v}{\|v\|}\|$? (Wow, that really doesn't typeset right... )

Comment: Since $\Vert c \mathbf{v} \Vert = |c| \Vert \mathbf{v} \Vert$, if $c = ( \Vert \mathbf{v} \Vert )^{-1}$, you get $\Vert c \mathbf{v} \Vert = 1$.

Comment: @rschwieb, yes I did. I do not understand what this means: $\Vert\alpha x\Vert=|\alpha|\Vert x\Vert$

Comment: your expression is NOT a vector since a vector divided by an scalar is just another vector

Comment: @Hans The answer is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/286919/55235).

Comment: @GitGud Thank you that post made me understand it!

Comment: @rschwieb I'm about to ask on meta what's the definition of a duplicate because the question itself is not a duplicate in the strict sense of the word.

Comment: @GitGud Sure, ask away. Since the other question contains "*There are a few pieces I am asked to find, and these are the one I am having trouble with: $|| \large \frac{\vec{u}}{|| \vec{u}||}||$*" and the solution you gave answers that question and this question, they are pretty darn close in my book :)

Comment: @rschwieb [I have](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10087/what-is-the-definition-of-duplicate-question), but people don't seem to be agreeing with you. I agree that my answer answers both the questions, but the thing is the questions itself are not duplicates, they don't ask the same thing, it just so happens that my answers serves as an answer to both the questions, so I think a more precise definition of **duplicate question** is in order.

Comment: I feel this is a terrible question. It would follow just because if it were the case (assuming $v=0$ for a contradiction), you would be dividing by 0...

Comment: @GitGud 4/5 is pretty good, although I feel anyone is perfectly within their rights to disagree :) Thanks for working to find a better definition of duplicate.